# A $3\times 3$ orthogonal matrix with trace zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

Let $A$ be an orthogonal matrix, that is, a real matrix such that $A^tA=I_3$. Can the trace of $A$ be 0 ?

Comment: An orthogonal matrix cannot be zero, since its determinant is $\pm 1$. So you should delete the word "non-zero".

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich Burde.

Comment: Consider a cyclic permutation.

Comment: Take the identity matrix and permute its columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a cyclic matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \cr
1 & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Is it an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Thanks Dietrich